# Difference between C++ files

Tags: c++

I just started a graphical C++ course and I have problem getting an overview how it is. 
we got some starting code, two files; one of type "C++ Source" and another of "C/C++ Header".
its supposed to be a graphical program which fills the screen with color.
also, we are using some custom libraries such as SDL and GLM, in the same folder as those two files there is a folder named gml and loads of subfolders, which I wont get into.

I have downloaded mingw, cmake and Visual Studio 11 beta for c++.

I've tried making a normal Win32 program and also a forms-application for the graphical part, but its always something wrong when compiling.

**My question:** how are you supposed to handle C++ files? I just got used to java and there its so easy to just open the .java file and paste into your IDE, dealing with C++ makes me really confused.

Comment: You're definitely going to need to go to your teacher on this, setting up a project is going to be more involved that what can be simply answered here. If you run into specific problems, a strange error message perhaps, we can help there.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"?

Comment: If the course doesn't cover C++ basics, I'd recommend [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: My best advice would be to use a bare console compiler **without IDE** to understand what you are asking for. But I feel that this might not be the best solution for you.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - you just neeed a long enough bargepole.  OP, get used to the phrase 'unresolved external'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm... Where to begin...

Somethings that happen behind the scenes in other languages are much more visible in C++. The process of obtaining a binary (say, an executable) from C++ involves first compiling the source code (There are sub-steps of this but the compiler handles them) to obtain object files, then the object files are linked by the linker to generate a binary.

In theory, you could simply `#include` all the cpp files in a project, and compile them all together and "link" (although there's nothing to link) but that would take a very long time, and more importantly, in complex projects that could deplete the memory available to your compiler.

So, we split our projects into compilation units, and by convention a .cpp file represents a single compilation unit. A compilation unit is the part of your project that gets compiled to generate one object file. Even though compilation units are compiled separately, some code has to be common among them, so that the piece of code in each of them can use the functionalities implemented by the others. .h files conventionally serve this purpose. Things are basically declared (sort of announced) in them, so that each compilation unit knows what to expect when it's a part of a linking process to generate a binary.

There's also the issue with libraries. You can find mainly two kinds of things in libraries;

- Already implemented functionality, shipped to you in the form of binary files including CPU instructions that can almost be run (but they've to be inserted in the right place). This form is accompanied by .h files to let your .cpp files know what to expect in the library.
- The second type is functionality implemented directly in the .h
  files. Yes, this is possible under special cases. There are cases,
  where the implementation has to (a weak has to) accompany the
  declaration (inlined functions, templated types etc.).

The first type comes in two flavors: A "static library" (.lib in windows, .a in linux), that enters your executable and becomes a part of it during linking, and a "dynamic library", that is exposed to your binary (so it knows about it) but that doesn't become a part of it. So, your executable will be looking for that dynamic library (.dll files in windows and .so files in linux f.x.) while it's run.

So, in order for your .cpp files to be able to receive services from libraries, they have to `#include` their .h files, to know about what there is in them. Later on, during linking, you have to show the linker where (what path in the file system) to find the binary components of those libraries. Finally, if the library is dynamic, the .dll's (or .so's etc.) must be accessible during run time (keep them in the same folder for instance).

While compiling your compilation units you have to tell the compiler where to find the .h files. Otherwise, all it will see will be `#include <something.h>` and it won't know where to find that file. with gcc, you tell the compiler with the `-I` option. Note that, you just tell the folder. Also of importance is that if the include directive looks like `#include<somefolder/somefile.h>` you shouldn't include `somefolder` in the path. So the invocation looks like:

```
g++ mycompilationunit.cpp -IPATH/TO/THE/INCLUDED/FILES -IPATH/TO/OTHER/INCLUDED/FILES -c
```

The `-c` option tells the compiler that it shouldn't attempt to make an executable just from this compilation unit, so it creates a .o file, to be linked with others later. Since we don't tell it the output file name, it spits out `mycompilationunit.o`.

Now we want to generate our binary (you probably want an executable, but you could also want to create a library of yours). So we have to tell the linker everything that goes into the binary. All the object files and all the static and dynamic libraries. So, we say: (Note g++ here also acts as the linker)

```
g++ objectfile1.o objectfile2.o objectfile3.o -LPATH/TO/LIBRARY/BINARIES -llibrary1 -llibrary2 -o myexecutable
```

Here, -L option is self explanatory in the example. -l option tells which binaries to look for. The linker will accept both static and dynamic libraries if it finds them on the path, and if it finds both, it'll choose one. Note that what goes after -l is not the full binary name. For instance in linux library names take the form `liblibrary.so.0` but they're referred to as -llibrary in the linker command. finally -o tells the compiler what name to give to your executable. You need some other options to f.x. create a dynamic library, but you probably don't need to know about them now.

Comment: wow, thanks for the heads up. i never thought someone would take that much time to explain, this was a really good answer - like an educative lesson :-)

regarding the "behind the scenes" i really feel that too now. i will go through some c++ tutorials to get the hang of it, just the fact that you need to direct the outputstream makes me think c++ needs more "instructions" compared to java for instance.

Answer (score 2):

[What is the difference between a .cpp file and a .h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875479/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cpp-file-and-a-h-file)

Look at this answer. Also a quick google search explains a bit too.

Pretty much .h (header) files are declerations and .cpp (source) files are definitions. It is possible to combine both files into one .cpp file but as projects get bigger and bigger its becomes annoying and almost unreasonable.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is a notion of a function declaration (the function signature) and a function definition (the actual code).

A header file (*.h) contains the declarations of functions and classes.  A source file (*.cpp, *.c++, *.C) contains the definitions.

A header file can be included in a source file using `#include` directive.

When you define a class in C++, you typically only include the declarations of the member functions (methods in Java lingo), and you put the class definition into a header file. The member function definitions containing the body of each function are typically put outside the class definition and into the source file.

Generally the best thing to do here is to get a book on C++ or C, and to look at some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Header files (.h) are supposed to contain definitions of classes, methods, and variables. Source file (.cpp) will contain the code. So in your .cpp file you need to include the header file as `#include "header-file-name.h"`.

Then use g++ to compile the .cpp file. Make sure that the path to .h file is correct.

If you are using CodeBlocks or Visual Studio, then just compiling the project and running will do everything for you. You can also add .h or .cpp file from there. You need not worry about anything.

Hope this helps.