# Why is there a difference between a .cpp file and a .h file?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.
Why can I access the variable when I include a .h file and not when I include a .cpp file in the following code?

file.h

```
int i = 10;
```

file.cpp

```
int i = 10;
```

main.cpp including .h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
     std::cout << i << std::endl;     // ok: output: 10
     return 0;
}
```

main.cpp including .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.cpp"

int main()
{
     std::cout << i << std::endl;     // error: LNK1169, LNK2005
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: There isn't a difference except for convention (and a very strong one at that). The difference is that Visual Studio compiles the cpp file, but not the h file.

Comment: `.cpp` files aren't supposed to be included, unless you want to screw up your build system.

Comment: Don't compile file.cpp. Than you can include it. (but it is a bad idea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a .cpp file and a .h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875479/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cpp-file-and-a-h-file)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here.

When you include a file, the included file is pasted into the including file before the compiler begins compiling. This means there is a complete copy of file.cpp in main.cpp that will be compiled.

Next, Visual Studio wants to compile cpp files. It sees file.cpp is part of the project, compiles it, and links it with the compiled output of main.cpp to make an executable program.

The linker now has to deal with two files (probably link.obj and main.obj) that have their own `int i`. The linker gives up and prints out a multiple definition error message. It doesn't even try to figure out which one is correct because only the intentions of the programmer makes one more correct than the other. You will have to wait for telepathic compiler support in a future C++ standard to sort that mess out. Until then don't do it.

Note what I wrote earlier about the included file being copied into the including. This means even with `int i` being defined in file.h you aren't out of trouble.

If main.cpp and future.cpp both include file.h, you once again have two files with `int i`. [Include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) will not help here because they only stop a header from being duplicated within one compiled file (a [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)).

The solution to this is don't define identifiers in headers unless you take steps to make them unique or tell the compiler that it's OK that they aren't. Strongly prefer not defining the identifier to the alternatives.

[For an identifier that is a variable use the `extern` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) to inform the compiler that `i`, or any other variable exists, but will be allocated elsewhere. You are then required to define the variable in exactly one elsewhere. eg:

file.h

```
extern int i;
```

file.cpp

```
int i = 0;
```

Now main.cpp or any other file can include file.h and use `i`. All of them are using the same `i`, so be careful with it. Be very, very careful. There is very often a better way to share a variable across multiple translation units, so spend the time looking for a different solution. You will most likely thank yourself when debugging time comes.

An alternative is to [define the variable as `static`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

file.h

```
static int i;
```

When using `static` every file that includes file .h has it's own `i` that is only visible within the including file. The linker is no longer involved. This is also almost always a bad idea. If you have variables that must be defined to support a header file, odds are good what the header *really* needs is a class.

[For an identifier that is a function, use the `inline` keyword.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Answer (score 1):

A `.h file` is considered a header file which contains only the declaration of functions and classes. A `.cpp file` on the other hand contains the definitions and has the main code.
Also `.cpp files` cannot be used in the `#include` statement.
For more information I suggest you take a look at this link:
[Why should I not include cpp files and instead use a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header)

Comment: Usually a header contains class definitions too. The .cpp has the definitions of the member functions.

Comment: This is also true. But usually the implementation is done in the .cpp files.