# What kind of information is stored in a .cpp file extension?

Tags: c++, file

I researched this question on Google and Stak Overflow but couldn't find an answer to it.

I am trying to find out what all information is stored in a .cpp file extension. Meaning, is it just code that has been compiled (meaning compiled code)? Does have an object file in it? Does it include an object in it? What exactly does it consist of?

Comment: it is c++ source code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because No effort to find an answer.

Comment: It's just a plain text file containing the source code.

Comment: I can't find an answer to this question specifically here on Stack Overflow or Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+stored+with+a+cpp+extension&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS779US779&oq=what+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i65l3.1654j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought it was more than source code, such as compiled code, or executable code?

Comment: I can't find a flat-out answer either, but if you read between the lines in the likes of [What is the difference between a .cpp file and a .h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875479/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cpp-file-and-a-h-file) you get a pretty good definition.

Comment: Ok, thank you pm100 and Bamar! I was totally overthinking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .h usually has the class definition (code)

```
#ifndef CLASS_T_H
#define CLASS_T_H

class class_t {
public:
    class_t();
    class_t(const class_t& o);

    ~class_t();

    class_t& operator=(const class_t& o);

private:

};

#endif
```

And the .cpp usually has the class implementation (code)

```
#include "class_t.h"

class_t::class_t() {

}

class_t::class_t(const class_t& o) {

}

class_t::~class_t() {

}

class_t& class_t::operator=(const class_t& o) {
    return *this;
}
```

You could use the class_t in another .cpp file by inclduing the .h file and compiling the cpp files into a binary executable.  One of the cpp files would contain your main() method.

Comment: So, maybe I am overthinking this and that it is just source code then?

Comment: yep ............

Comment: @SeanV Overthinking. By convention cpp is uncompiled implementation source code.

Comment: yeah, by convention.  I was going to add that to the answer but decided against it

Comment: @SeanV Here's a pretty good quick rundown of how all of the parts interact and get transformed into a program: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you user458301 and Abdul!

Comment: npaa @SeanV ....